# Textbook on smooth manifolds with many carefully worked out examples?

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds

Lee's textbook on smooth manifolds is great, but his examples tend to not be worked out in much detail, which is kind of painful for a new student. Are there textbooks that work out their examples in greater detail? Alternatively, is there a textbook with many simple problems (I don't need to move to hard problems yet), all of which have solutions?

Comment: You should probably tell what you want to do with manifolds (physics of general relativity ? theoretical maths, differential geometry, algebraic geometry, Riemann surfaces ?)

Comment: @user1952009 Something with a scope that is a subset of (or equal to) Lee's textbook on SMs is what I am looking for.